# Grouped Index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, window-functions

I'm building a table in MySQL and need to build a "grouped index" row that increments, but resets for new values in another column. Like this:

```
1 Apple
2 Apple
3 Apple
1 Banana
2 Banana
1 Pear
2 Pear
3 Pear
4 Pear
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: And what happens if there are two groups of "Apple"s.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, just use `row_number()`:

```
select
    row_number() over(partition by fruit order by ?) rn,
    fruit
from mytable
```

Note that, for your answer to produce *consistent* results, you need another column that can be used to *order* the records. I represented that as `?` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

If you use mysql 5.x  you can use this Query

> ```
> CREATE TABLE fruit (
>
>   `fruit` VARCHAR(6)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO fruit
>   ( `fruit`)
> VALUES
>   ( 'Apple'),
>   ( 'Apple'),
>   ( 'Apple'),
>   ( 'Banana'),
>   ( 'Banana'),
>   ( 'Pear'),
>   ( 'Pear'),
>   ( 'Pear'),
>   ( 'Pear');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> IF(fruit = @fruit, @row_number := @row_number +1,@row_number := 1) rownumber
> ,@fruit := fruit
> FROM
>   (SELECT * From fruit ORDER BY fruit ASC) t, (SELECT @row_number := 0) a,(SELECT @fruit := '') b ;
> ```
>
> ```
> rownumber | @fruit := fruit
> --------: | :--------------
>         1 | Apple          
>         2 | Apple          
>         3 | Apple          
>         1 | Banana         
>         2 | Banana         
>         1 | Pear           
>         2 | Pear           
>         3 | Pear           
>         4 | Pear
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6b881a2d9f62c9f185af3c58e4b2d353)*

The **order** of the **columns** has to be this way, so that the **algorithm can work**. If you need it in mysql to change, please use a an outer SELECT